# TreeView/ScrollView rendering bug with bitmaps?

Tags: wpf, scroll, bitmap, treeview

There is a WPF (.NET 3.5) TreeView, which contains bitmaps.
Nothing special:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ctrlOutputTree" TargetType="{x:Type vo:OutputTreeView}">
    <TreeView x:Name="OutputTree" ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource TreeViewItemStyle}"
              KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Cycle" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"  MouseDown="OutputTree_MouseDown"
              Loaded="OutputTree_Loaded" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor">

        <TreeView.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
                <EventSetter Event="RequestBringIntoView" Handler="OutputTree_RequestBringIntoView"/>
                <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding Path=IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            </Style>
        </TreeView.Resources>

        <TreeViewItem  ItemsSource="{Binding Converter={StaticResource featureDiffsSourceCreator},Mode=OneWay}"
                       IsExpanded="True" Margin="0,4,0,0" 
                       KeyDown="AttrDiffTreeviewItem_KeyDown">
        </TreeViewItem>
    </TreeView>
</ControlTemplate>
```

TreeViewItems:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ImageTemplate">
    <Image VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="3,1,0,0" 
           RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor"
           RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"
           Stretch="None">
        <Image.Source>
            <!-- <BitmapImage UriSource="c:\\imageBMP_test.bmp" />-->

            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource imageConverter}">
                <Binding Path=....
            </MultiBinding>
        </Image.Source>
    </v:Image>
</ControlTemplate>
```

The bitmaps are generated as BitmapSource in imageConverter (from native control).

```
System::Drawing::Bitmap^ b = System::Drawing::Image::FromHbitmap((IntPtr)aBmp);
IntPtr hb = b->GetHbitmap();
System::Windows::Media::Imaging::BitmapSource^ bs = 
    System::Windows::Interop::Imaging::CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(hb, 
                             System::IntPtr::Zero,
                             Int32Rect(0,0,nWidth,nHeight),
                             BitmapSizeOptions::FromEmptyOptions());
```

It displays all fine, but when we scroll the tree, sometimes bitmaps becomes distorted. Mostly close to the bottom. Sometimes we need to resize the tree to happen, but it happens sooner or later.

ItemX is text, and the table next to it is the bitmap.
[image]

After this, when it's wrong, if I scroll the tree with the scrollbar-position-thumb, just 1 pixel up/down, it becomes sharp and good again.
But if I scroll with up/down arrows on the scrollbar, bitmaps remain invalid for a few click (then goes away)

If I replace the BitmapSource generation in XAML `MultiBinding/imageConverter`  --> `<BitmapImage UriSource="c:\\imageBMP_test.bmp"` , then don't experience this issue. (I have to take care the imageBMP_test.bmp to be 24 bits & 96DPI, otherwise also not good)

If I change the BitmapSource generation to read from file (24 or 32bit bmp with 96dpi):

```
System::Drawing::Bitmap^ b = gcnew System::Drawing::Bitmap("c:\\imageBMP24_96dpi_small.bmp");
IntPtr hb = b->GetHbitmap();
System::Windows::Media::Imaging::BitmapSource^ bs = 
    System::Windows::Interop::Imaging::CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(hb, 
                             System::IntPtr::Zero,
                             Int32Rect(0,0,nWidth,nHeight),
                             BitmapSizeOptions::FromEmptyOptions());
```

Then after some scrolling, I got this:
[image]

Any help, idea would be appreciated.

What I tried:
Checked, generated 'BitmapSource' is 96 DPI.
Saved into file all generated 'BitmapSource' - all were fine, while they were distorted on the screen.
I am out of ideas, seems it's a WPF bug? Or maybe video driver? (nvidia quadro/laptop/win7 64bit)

**SO IN SHORT**

TreeView displays bitmap loaded from file specified in XAML: **OK** (very small glitches here also sometimes, but those are acceptable)
TreeView displays bitmap from BitmapSource generated: **FAILS sometimes** (during scroll)

Comment: just for fun try using a `ViewBox` and see.

Comment: @AnjumSKhan can you give more details, where should I use it?

Comment: Btw, I extended the original question with more info/example/screenshot

Comment: `<ControlTemplate x:Key="ImageTemplate"><ViewBox>...</ViewBox></ControlTemplate>`

Comment: Tried, same result... [link](http://oi66.tinypic.com/200pldx.jpg)  
Also same, if I specify directly the bitmap in the XAML `<BitmapImage UriSource="c:\\imageBMP_test.bmp" />` instead of Converter, it's ok.

Comment: What it seems, if I handle `ScrollViewer_ScrollChanged` for the tree, and add: `if (changedScrollViewer.VerticalOffset == changedScrollViewer.ScrollableHeight) { changedScrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(changedScrollViewer.VerticalOffset - 10.95); } ` -> this seems (so far, with quick test) to prevent the issue. So basically I do not allow to scroll to the end. Pity I cannot really use this (or will be very difficult)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.
Have no clue why it works, but seems to solve the problem:

if in the imageConverter (in a native control) I return BitmapImage^ instead of BitmapSource^, it's ok.
Very strange, but I just create BitmapImage from the BitmapSource, return that, and no problems.
WPF is horrible...