# Image size in TreeView depends on image color bit depth

Tags: wpf, image, bitmap, treeview, treeviewitem

I am experiencing a very strange thing: a TreeView contains items (Images), declared this way in XAML:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ImageTemplate">
    <Image VerticalAlignment="Top" 
           Visibility="{Binding IsImageVisible,Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility}}"
           RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor"
           SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
           Stretch="None">
        <Image.Source>
            <BitmapImage UriSource="c:\\imageBMP4.bmp" />
            <!-- <BitmapImage UriSource="c:\\imageBMP8.bmp" /> -->
            <!-- <BitmapImage UriSource="c:\\imageBMP24.bmp" /> -->
            <!-- <BitmapImage UriSource="c:\\imageBMP32.bmp" /> -->
            <!-- <BitmapImage UriSource="c:\\imagePNG8.png" /> -->
            <!-- <BitmapImage UriSource="c:\\imagePNG24.png" /> -->
            <!-- <BitmapImage UriSource="c:\\imagePNG32.png" /> -->
            <!-- <BitmapImage UriSource="c:\\imageJPG24.jpg" /> -->
        </Image.Source>
    </Image>
</ControlTemplate>
```

All image are 640*480, filled with blue-white horizontal 1 pixel lines.

What I experience, if I use 4 or 8 bit bitmaps (bmp), they are rendered fine, pixel to pixel on the screen, size 640*480 in the tree.
(however, scrolling the tree to the end causes rendering problems if more images are in the tree, see: [TreeView/ScrollView rendering bug with bitmaps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38742304/treeview-renders-invalid-bitmaps-when-scrolled-to-bottom) )
Rendered image (8 bit bmp) in the tree (half sized):

[image]

However if I change to 24 or 32 bit image (bmp/png/jpg), they are strecthed to 853*640 (1.33 * original size), thus displayed strecthed/blurred. 
(however, this case, scrolling the tree to the end works fine, no rendering issues)
Rendered image (24 bit bmp) in the tree (half sized):

[image]

What is this behavior, and why? Simple changing the bit depth of the source image why changes the rendered image dimensions?

Comment: I think this could be the reason: `Actually, I've seen that regularly with PNG images. It seems that the default resolution for PNG is 72dpi, while the default screen resolution in WPF is 96dpi. WPF tries to take this into account by rendering png bitmaps scaled to 133% of their pixel size, which is technically correct but normally not what the user wants. You can either use a gif or jpg instead, or you can combine the image with a LayoutTransform scaling it to 0.75 of its size, or just stick with setting the size of the image control explicitly.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got the problem: WPF default DPI is 96, while my bitmaps were 72. Except the 8 and 4 bits, those were unspecified (this case the default 96 was considered).
I converted bitmaps to 96dpi, and no resizing anymore.
For more details, see the comment under the question.